# Remove the orange "connecting" banner in Skype

Tags: macos, mac, skype

Lately when I sign into Skype, there is an orange banner at the top that says "Connecting" and it never goes away. I can still make and receive calls, but audio only; I can't see the video broadcast by others in the call (although they say they can see me). I've tried signing out and back in, and even rebooted the computer to no avail. How do I get rid of it?